# getting coordinates of svg element returns SVGAnimatedLength

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

I tried a simple test to understand the behaviour of svg + JS, since I need to check if a certain SVG object is on a svg path and act accordingly. When trying to explicitly access the .cx or .cy properties of an SVG element, in this case an ellipse, instead of obtaining the coordinates I get an SVGAnimatedLength object.

```html
<svg
   id="contenedorCirculo"
   width="200mm"
   height="200mm"
   viewBox="0 0 200 200"
   version="1.1"
>
<g
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   id="layer3"
   inkscape:label="points">
<ellipse
 style="fill:#ff00e5;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fbde00;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
 id="circulo"
 cx="50"
 cy="50"
 rx="5"
 ry="5" />

</g>
</svg>

<script>
//this returns SVGAnimatedLength { baseVal: SVGLength, animVal: SVGLength }
console.log(document.getElementById("circulo").cx);

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for the value. Because of [SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) there's an [animated value and a base value](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedLength) for many SVG attributes. Unless you're actually using SMIL the [`animVal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString/animVal) and the [`baseVal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString/baseVal) will be the same

If you want to set the value you should set the `baseVal`; the `animVal` can only be set through SMIL.

```html
<svg
   id="contenedorCirculo"
   width="200mm"
   height="200mm"
   viewBox="0 0 200 200"
   version="1.1"
>
<g
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   id="layer3"
   inkscape:label="points">
<ellipse
 style="fill:#ff00e5;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fbde00;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
 id="circulo"
 cx="50"
 cy="50"
 rx="5"
 ry="5" />

</g>
</svg>

<script>
//this returns SVGAnimatedLength { baseVal: SVGLength, animVal: SVGLength }
console.log(document.getElementById("circulo").cx.animVal.value);

</script>
```